# Request time out error

Tags: networking, network-protocols

Hi Today i came across strange problem whenever i try to pinging to my server works properly but whenever i send http request from browser the request time out happens.

can anybody help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Can you telnet to port 80 on your server?

```
telnet <server_host_or_ip_address> 80
```

If not, is the server listening on port 80?

```
netstat -lntp | grep :80
```

If not is your webserver daemon running?

*Apache for instance*

```
ps auxw | grep [h]ttpd
```

If your webserver daemon is running and listening on port 80 but you still cannot connect it's probably a firewall rule.

Answer (score 0):

The server responding to a ping means that it received an ICMP packet, and transmitted a response.  That is ALL that ping means.  It has nothing to do with the HTTP protocol on port 80.  It sounds like the server is up, but the web service on the machine is down / broken.